# Characterizing all simple algebraic ring extensions of $\mathbb{C}[x]$ having no prime elements

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, unique-factorization-domains

Let $w$ be an algebraic element over $\mathbb{C}[x]$, with minimal polynomial $f(t)=c_mt^m+\cdots+c_1t+c_0$, $c_i \in \mathbb{C}[x]$.

> Is it possible to characterize (in terms of the $c_j$'s) all algebraic elements $w$, such that $R=\mathbb{C}[x][w]$ has no prime elements?

Please see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2276356/a-simple-algebraic-ring-extension-of-a-ufd-having-no-prime-elements/2276385#2276385) related question, in which the special case $k[x^2][x^3]$ is dealt with (notice that in this special case, $m=2$ with $c_2=1$, namely, $w$ is integral).

Comment: This is far from being a full characterisation: In the integral case, if the curve given by $f$ is smooth, then there are no prime elements whenever the curve has positive genus. Because a prime element would mean that the corresponding point on the curve is linear equivalent to the point at infinity in the projective closure. This can only happen for rational curves by a well known lemma.

Comment: Thank you very much! Additional partial answers (from you or other people) are also welcome.

Comment: @MooS This is not quite correct, several things can go wrong. In particular, there could be several points at infinity and then things don't work so easily.

Comment: @Mohan, please, do you have any ideas what happens if $f$ is not monic, namely, $w$ is not integral? Which case (integral or not integral) is easier to deal with, in your opinion?

Comment: I would suspect the integral case is simpler, but I do not think there can be any simple criterion without dealing with what happens at infinity.

Comment: Just as an example, consider $R=\mathbb{C}[x][w]$ with $w^2=x^4+x$. You can easily check that this is a smooth curve of genus one. But, $w-x^2$  is a prime defining the origin $x=w=0$.

Comment: @user26857, I guess that your comment is closely related to the second answer in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277193/prime-elements-of-mathbbcx-which-remain-prime-in-a-simple-algebraic-ring.